# No notification sent on Yammer through Ant

Tags: email, ant, yammer

I want to send notification on Yammer through Ant, but no notification are sent.

I am referring to [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20120422100512/https://www.yammer.com/company/email).

```
<target name="notify_yammer">
    <mail mailhost="${mail_host_name}" mailport="25" user="${mail_host_user}" password="${mail_host_password}" subject="Test build completion notification" charset="utf-8">
        <from address="${mail_from_address}" />
        <to address="${mail_to_address}" />
        <message>Build successfully deployed on server!</message>
    </mail>
</target>
```

After executing above task `notify_yammer`, I got this output:

```
Buildfile: /home/Repository/myProject/build.xml

notify_yammer:
     [mail] Sending email: Test build completion notification
     [mail] Sent email with 0 attachments
**BUILD SUCCESSFUL**
Total time: 5 seconds
```

But I received no notification on Yammer.

Is there any changes required in [Notification Settings](https://www.yammer.com/account/notifications)? Or can you tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yammer site is down for 2 days so no notification on yammer.

i.e Site is down on 19Nov - 20 Nov.

Now Successful Email/Feed Notification on yammmer through ANT.